# converting a python requests program into a call to curl

Tags: python, curl

I have a python program that makes a get request and prints the result. Some of the inputs are lists of strings rather than just strings and so I am unsure how to convert this to a call to curl. Also I am not sure what this sort of thing is called so I have been unable to find anything about it online. Below I have given a minimal example of what I am trying to do.

How can I convert the following python program into a call to curl?

```
import requests
URL = "http://example.com/script.php"
PARAMS = {'param1':['val1','val2']}
print(requests.get(URL,PARAMS).text)
```

I tried the following:

```
curl "https://example.com/script.php?param1=['val1','val2']"
```

however I got this error:

```
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range specification in column 40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the *url* manually:

`curl "http://example.com/script.php?param1=val&param2=val2"`

In this case:

`curl "http://example.com/script.php?param1=[val1,val2]"` or

`curl "http://example.com/script.php?param1=val1,val2"`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work, I'll post to my question the error I get in just a moment

Comment: I like your answer however the first line does not reflect my question and the second doesn't work, the third works perfectly though. I would recommend removing all but the last line of code and then maybe giving some more context around it.

Comment: @fred, first version is a generic way of filling the get request for curl. The other ones depends on how the service are parsing the url, since it is not for a specific website I think its ok to offer some options. Take into account that this is not only for you, but some other people may have the same problem.